# Correct way to inject pure class into angular 1.x application in ES6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

A colleague claims this is an incorrect way to inject a pure ES6 JavaScript class into Angular. I am curious if there is a better way (more correct)?

As an aside, is it better (and why is it better) to attach the injected dependencies (`$timeout` in this example) to the instance; e.g., `this._$timeout = $timeout` in the constructor. I personally think there is no advantage to doing that in this case.

**class.factory.js**

```
let ClassFactory = function($timeout) {
    // Factory function that simply returns class constructor.

    class MyClass {
        constructor(a, b) {
            // contrived class
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = null;
        }

        applyChange() {
            // contrived class method
            const SELF = this;

            $timeout(() => {
                SELF.c = SELF.a + SELF.b;
            });
        }
    }

    return MyClass ;
};

ClassFactory.$inject = ['$timeout'];

export default ClassFactory;
```

**app.module.js**

```
import ClassFactory from './factories/class.factory';
import AppService from './services/app.service';


export default angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('ClassFactory', ClassFactory)
    .service('AppService', AppService);
```

Later, elsewhere we may use the class in some service or controller, to construct new MyClass instances.

**app.service.js**

```
class AppService {
    // contrived usage of our dependency injected pure class.

    constructor(ClassFactory) {
        this.array = [];
        this._ClassFactory = ClassFactory;
    }

    initialize(a, b) {
        // We can instantiate as many "MyClass" objects as we need.
        let myClass = new this._ClassFactory(a, b);

        this.array.push(myClass);
    }

    static serviceFactory(...injected) {
        AppService.instance = new AppService(...injected);
        return AppService.instance;
    }
}

AppService.serviceFactory.$inject = ['ClassFactory'];

export default AppService.serviceFactory;
```

Comment: Doing things like AppService.instance = new AppService is also not advisable. It will likely work as expected normally because there's only 1 app instance, and a service is a singleton. But it will cause memory leaks during testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point it doesn't matter if `$timeout` is class property or just local variable.

Wrapping a class with factory function doesn't play well with ES6 development , it's not possible to export and extend it. The fact that a factory is needed probably indicates design problem.

A class like that can get the dependencies via dependency injection (in [common sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)). This is a usual thing when class constructor is supposed to be called with non-dependency arguments too:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor($timeout, a, b) {
    this._$timeout = $timeout;
    ...
  }
}
...
obj = new MyClass($timeout, a, b);
```

If there's more than one dependency, `$injector` dependency can be provided instead of all dependencies:

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor($injector, a, b) {
    this._$timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
    ...
  }
}
...
obj = new MyClass($injector, a, b);
```

There may also be a design problem that causes the dependency on `$timeout`, and by solving it the dependency could be avoided. It's not clear from the code above why `MyClass` should trigger a digest with `$timeout`, its logic doesn't contain anything that would require that. It's the responsibility of code that uses `MyClass` instance and binds it to view or whatever a digest is there for.

Comment: It's a contrived example. But in the actual class, we need access to some Angular features. A real use for `$timeout` is to trigger an Angular digest cycle (under narrow conditions) so changes in the class instance propagate.

Comment: Can you give an example of using `$injector` with our example here? And to your other comments, I did not find any good resources explaining how to use pure ES6 classes with Angular. Using a factory to return the class was the closest thing I could find.

Comment: @TechMedicNYC Added. Yes, it's rather low-profile case, not something that is usually discussed in guides. Factory function is the way it would be done in non-modular ES5, but it doesn't look good enough for ES6.